# xcode is showing error compiling the codes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Here:-

import UIKit

class ViewController : UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!

```
@IBOutlet weak var statepickerbtn: UIButton!

let states = ["alaska","alabama","akansas","california","maine","new york"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    statePicker.dataSource = self
    statePicker.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func statebtnpressed(_ sender: Any) {

    func numberOfComponents(in: <#T##UIPickerView#>)-> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    func pickerView(<#T##pickerView: UIPickerView##UIPickerView#>, numberOfRowsInComponent: <#T##Int#>)->Int
    {
        return states.count
    }


    func pickerView(<#T##pickerView: UIPickerView##UIPickerView#>, titleForRow: <#T##Int#>, forComponent: <#T##Int#>) -> String?
    {
        return states[row]
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What error you are getting?..

Comment: /Users/arishtripathi/Desktop/prog/miraclepill/miraclepill/ViewController.swift:32:37: Use of undeclared type '<#T##UIPickerView#>'

Comment: /Users/arishtripathi/Desktop/prog/miraclepill/miraclepill/ViewController.swift:11:7: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Are adding delegate methods on wrong place. Don't put pickers delegates methods inside button action.

```
class ViewController : UIViewController,UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate { 

   @IBOutlet weak var statepickerbtn: UIButton!
   @IBOutlet weak var statePicker: UIPickerView!
   let states = ["alaska","alabama","akansas","california","maine","new york"]

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    statePicker.dataSource = self
    statePicker.delegate = self
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }

  @IBAction func statebtnpressed(_ sender: Any) { 
  //Do not place delegates method inside this action method. Instead of this use show hide procedure on picker view.

   }

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return states.count

}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return states[row]
}

}
```

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: @arishtripathi Also remove all `<`, `#` and `>`.

Comment: pasted this on Xcode ,aint working

Comment: this time there are only 2 errors

Comment: can you post error ?

Comment: /Users/arishtripathi/Desktop/prog/miraclepill/miraclepill/ViewController.swift:11:7: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Comment: /Users/arishtripathi/Desktop/prog/miraclepill/miraclepill/ViewController.swift:11:7: Type 'ViewController' does not conform to protocol 'UIPickerViewDataSource'

Comment: Check again ! it is fine !